# Number format in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, report, builder

I want to format the number like this:
(note:blank space is displayed as N/A)

14.3453453 is displayed as 14.35

12.1E-02 is displayed as 0.01

0 is displayed as 0.0 0

1 is displayed as 1.0 0

Every number upto 2 decimal places. But when I applied filter ya format expression, there is an error in place of a blank space, I want N/A there instead .

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to do this using just the `Format` property. You will probably have to change the textbox's `Value` expression.

Try something like this.

```
=IIF(
     IsNumeric(Fields!myField.Value),
     Format(Fields!myField.Value, "f2"),
     "N/A"
    )
```